# Postfix performance and how to increase my throughput?

Tags: postfix, performance, email-server

What I've read so far:

- Postfix Tunning
- Postfix Bottle Neck Analisys
- The Book of Postfix (chapter 22)

I have similar specs to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683972/what-is-the-average-capacity-of-a-postfix-mail-server) but I'm only able to send about ~1300 emails/hour

What I've done:

- Reduced the time for deferred mails
- Reduced deferred scans
- List item
- Increase maximal backoff time

Some configurations

```
queue_run_delay = 300s
minimal_backoff_time = 600s
maximal_backoff_time = 3600s
default_process_limit = 100
smtp_connect_timeout = 30s
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20s
initial_destination_concurrency = 5s
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2s
virtual_destination_concurrency_limit = 20s
```

Amavis, clamav, postgrey and spamassasing are also working with postfix and every email is signed by opendkim, the server is used for email marketing and that's why the added services, should I remove them? how much would that affect the reputation of the emails sent?

Comment: The question first is why aren't you getting more throughput (supposing you could). Is the CPU maxed out? Is the disk IO bottlenecking? Is the RAM maxed out? Is your network saturated? Are you sufferring from throttling from Yahoo/AOL/Gmail/etc? Are you just getting bounced? How do you could 1300 emails/hour?

Comment: Right now the server’s ram is almost full, that's why I was thinking on removing some services specially clamav since is the one consuming most of the ram

Comment: default_destination_concurrency_limit - you have it in "seconds", but it is not a time unit. Or is it?